# Store object files in separate directory using make

Tags: makefile, fortran, mingw, gfortran

I'm running a makefile using mingw on windows. I've seen a lot of SO links about this topic, but they all seem to be for C or c++. I'm not sure if the same rules apply, and since I'm using windows, syntax seems to be a bit different too. Here are some of the other references:

[How to place object files in separate subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178125/gnu-make-how-to-get-object-files-in-separate-subdirectory#comment5830589_5178125)    (most promising, I think)

[Using a make file to compile files in separate directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044433/using-a-make-file-to-compile-files-in-separate-directories)

[Flat object file directory structure output with GNU Make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365305/flat-object-file-directory-structure-output-with-gnu-make)

What I currently have is (verbatim)

```
VPATH =\
    user \
    static \
    computations \
    solvers\\steadyState \
    solvers\\transient \
    solvers\\transient\\momentum \
    solvers\\transient\\induction

FC      = gfortran
TOP_DIR = .
MOD_DIR = $(TOP_DIR)\\mod
OBJ_DIR = $(TOP_DIR)\\obj

FCFLAGS = -g
FCFLAGS += -J$(MOD_DIR) -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized

TARGET = parametricStudy

SRCS_F =\
    user\\constants.f90 \
    static\\myExceptions.f90 \
    static\\myDebug.f90 \
    static\\scalarField.f90 \
    static\\vectorField.f90 \
    static\\myIO.f90 \
    user\\simParams.f90 \
    static\\solverSettings.f90 \
    static\\myTime.f90 \
    computations\\myError.f90 \
    static\\coordinates.f90 \
    user\\griddata.f90 \
    static\\myAllocate.f90 \
    static\\BCs.f90 \
    user\\rundata.f90 \
    computations\\myDel.f90 \
    computations\\vectorOps.f90 \
    static\\myExport.f90 \
    computations\\applyBCs.f90 \
    solvers\\steadyState\\mySOR.f90 \
    solvers\\steadyState\\myPoisson.f90 \
    solvers\\transient\\induction\\initializeBBCs.f90 \
    solvers\\transient\\induction\\initializeBfield.f90 \
    solvers\\transient\\induction\\initializeSigmaMu.f90 \
    solvers\\transient\\momentum\\initializeUBCs.f90 \
    solvers\\transient\\momentum\\initializeUfield.f90 \
    solvers\\transient\\inductionSolver.f90 \
    solvers\\transient\\momentumSolver.f90 \
    solvers\\transient\\MHDSolver.f90 \
    user\\MOONS.f90 \
    parametricStudy.f90

OBJS_F = $(patsubst %.f90,$(OBJ_DIR)\\%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS_F)))

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS_F)
    $(FC) -o $@ $(FCFLAGS) $(OBJS_F)

$(OBJ_DIR)\\%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
clean:
    del $(OBJ_DIR)\\*.o $(MOD_DIR)\\*.mod parametricStudy.exe
list:;  @echo " "
    @echo " "
    @echo "Source files:"
    @echo $(SRCS_F)
    @echo " "
    @echo "Object files:"
    @echo $(OBJS_F)
    @echo " "
    @echo "Compiler          : $(FC)"
    @echo "Include directory : $(INC_DIR)"
    @echo "Root directory    : $(ROOT_DIR)"
    @echo "Bin directory     : $(BIN_DIR)"
    @echo "Modules directory : $(MOD_DIR)"
    @echo "Modules directory : $(MOD_DIR)"
    @echo "Object directory  : $(OBJ_DIR)"
    @echo " "
```

Using this, I can execute the following (again, verbatim)

```
C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\development\FORTRAN_LIB>gmake
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\const
ants.o user/constants.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\myExc
eptions.o static/myExceptions.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\myDeb
ug.o static/myDebug.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\scala
rField.o static/scalarField.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\vecto
rField.o static/vectorField.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\myIO.
o static/myIO.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\simPa
rams.o user/simParams.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\solve
rSettings.o static/solverSettings.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\myTim
e.o static/myTime.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\myErr
or.o computations/myError.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\coord
inates.o static/coordinates.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\gridd
ata.o user/griddata.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\myAll
ocate.o static/myAllocate.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\BCs.o
 static/BCs.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\runda
ta.o user/rundata.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\myDel
.o computations/myDel.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\vecto
rOps.o computations/vectorOps.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\myExp
ort.o static/myExport.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\apply
BCs.o computations/applyBCs.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\mySOR
.o solvers\\steadyState/mySOR.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\myPoi
sson.o solvers\\steadyState/myPoisson.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\initi
alizeBBCs.o solvers\\transient\\induction/initializeBBCs.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\initi
alizeBfield.o solvers\\transient\\induction/initializeBfield.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\initi
alizeSigmaMu.o solvers\\transient\\induction/initializeSigmaMu.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\initi
alizeUBCs.o solvers\\transient\\momentum/initializeUBCs.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\initi
alizeUfield.o solvers\\transient\\momentum/initializeUfield.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\induc
tionSolver.o solvers\\transient\\induction/inductionSolver.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\momen
tumSolver.o solvers\\transient\\momentum/momentumSolver.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\MHDSo
lver.o solvers\\transient/MHDSolver.f90
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized -c -o .\\obj\MOONS
.o user/MOONS.f90
gmake: *** No rule to make target `.\\obj\parametricStudy.o', needed by `paramet
ricStudy'.  Stop.

C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\development\FORTRAN_LIB>gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -
c -o .\\obj\parametricStudy.o parametricStudy.f90

C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\development\FORTRAN_LIB>gmake
gfortran -o parametricStudy -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized
 .\\obj\constants.o .\\obj\myExceptions.o .\\obj\myDebug.o .\\obj\scalarField.o
.\\obj\vectorField.o .\\obj\myIO.o .\\obj\simParams.o .\\obj\solverSettings.o .\
\obj\myTime.o .\\obj\myError.o .\\obj\coordinates.o .\\obj\griddata.o .\\obj\myA
llocate.o .\\obj\BCs.o .\\obj\rundata.o .\\obj\myDel.o .\\obj\vectorOps.o .\\obj
\myExport.o .\\obj\applyBCs.o .\\obj\mySOR.o .\\obj\myPoisson.o .\\obj\initializ
eBBCs.o .\\obj\initializeBfield.o .\\obj\initializeSigmaMu.o .\\obj\initializeUB
Cs.o .\\obj\initializeUfield.o .\\obj\inductionSolver.o .\\obj\momentumSolver.o
.\\obj\MHDSolver.o .\\obj\MOONS.o .\\obj\parametricStudy.o
```

Note that after I receive the error, I can explicitly compile the parametricStudy.f90 after the error with:

```
 gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -c -o .\\obj\parametricStudy.o parametricStudy.f90
```

and then type

```
 gmake
```

Again, which results in no errors. I'm very puzzled.

Here is a screenshot[image] of my directory:

Maybe it has something to do with TARGET? It seems like the path of the last file is somehow wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using GNU make from Cygwin or MinGW?

Comment: im using mingw actually

Comment: I think. I run the makefe with gmake or mingw32-make

Comment: Are you still getting no rule to make `parametricStudy.o`? If so please run `dir` in the directory containing the makefile and post the output.

Comment: Yes I am. I updated the question the other day. It should be up to date. I'll double check at 1:30pm today.

Comment: I updated the question. The directory should be clear by the specification of the source files in the makefile. Maybe this is a compiler bug @MikeKinghan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following style of makefile solves the problems. I tested it with a specimen C
project, not fortran, but that is immaterial to the `make` problem and solution.

```
# VPATH: Tell `make` to look for in `user` for prerequisites it can't find here
VPATH = user
# If e.g. you also want `make` to look for for prerequisites in `../include`, then:
# VPATH = user:../include
FC      = gfortran
TOP_DIR = .
MOD_DIR = $(TOP_DIR)\\mod
OBJ_DIR = $(TOP_DIR)\\obj

FCFLAGS = -g
FCFLAGS += -J$(MOD_DIR) -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized

TARGET = parametricStudy

SRCS_F =\
    user\\constants.f90 \
    ...
    parametricStudy.f90

OBJS_T1 = $(patsubst %.f90,%.o,$(SRCS_F))
OBJS_T2 = $(notdir $(OBJS_T1))
# The object files are all to be obj\<name>.o
OBJS_F = $(patsubst %.o,$(OBJ_DIR)\\%.o,$(OBJS_T2))

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS_F)
    $(FC) -o $@ $(FCFLAGS) $(OBJS_F)

# How to make an obj\*.o from the matching *.f90. `make` considers the VPATH
$(OBJ_DIR)\\%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
clean:
    del $(OBJ_DIR)\\*.o $(MOD_DIR)\\*.mod parametricStudy.exe
```

Using a relative path `TOP_DIR = .` rather than an absolute `ROOT_DIR` is good advice already offered
by @Wintermute.

To enable the required pattern rule:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)\\%.o: %.f90
```

to kick in, you must make it appear to `make` that any prerequisite `*.f90` is right here, as per the pattern,
not in some other directory like, e.g. `user\constants.f90` That is what the `VPATH`
achieves.

**Continued for later developments**

Not yet having seen a listing of the directory where the makefile resides I
can only venture a hypothesis, but the hypothesis suggested by what I do see is:

The directory does not actually contain a file called `parametricStudy.f90`,
but a file called `parametricStudy.F90`, and if it is renamed to `parametricStudy.f90`,
then the makefile will find and compile it.

Is that right?

How this explains the facts: The pattern rule:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)\\%.o: %.f90
```

is failing to match any `parametricStudy.f90`, so there is no such file. You say however that:

```
gfortran -g -J.\\mod -fopenmp -c -o .\\obj\parametricStudy.o parametricStudy.f90
```

successfully compiles.

You are  building on Windows, so the toolchain subscribes to Windows' file-handling protocols.
Filenames are case-insentive: `parametricStudy.f90` will identify `parametricStudy.F90`, if it exists,
and `.F90` will be interpreted by `gfortran` (on Windows or anywhere else) as denoting a
Fortran 90 source file. Thus the successful commandline compile.

But the pattern rule is indifferent to file-handling protocols. It is just a pattern
matching rule, and the invariant `.f90` is not matched by `.F90`.

Comment: This is so close to fully working! All of the files, except the last one (parametricStudy.f90) are compiled to .object files. It would be really nice for that last .f90 file to be located in an absolute path (I want to separate my code and simulation results). Is there a way that I can make VPATH include the root directory? (I tried ".", but that didn't work). It would be even nicer if I could make VPATH include an absolute path. Also, the executable is not being made since the last file is not successfully made.

Comment: parametricStudy.f90 does not get compiled?  There must be still be a mistake in the makefile. Suggest you post it exactly as it is now.

Comment: P.S. Am I right in assuming that `parametricStudy.f90` *is in* the directory where you are running `make`?

Comment: And just to be sure, `parametricStudy.f90` *is in* the directory where you are running make?

Comment: Yeah, I've got makefile, parametricStudy, user (folder), etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69572/discussion-between-charlie-and-mike-kinghan).

Comment: Would, but it's my bedtime. Work tomorrow. Back on the case tomorrow night. Cheers.

Comment: no, the file parametricStudy.f90 exists in the same directory as the makefile before compile time

Comment: @Charlie The issue isn't whether the file exists in the correct directory, but whether it has a correct extension. An extension of `f9O` or `F90` might look correct, but this will confuse `make.

Comment: @MikeKinghan You are absolutely right. That one file, was the only one that had the extension .F90, all others, for some reason were .f90. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Charlie You're welcome. That was a workout. There are some lose ends to tie off in my answer but it's bedtime again. Do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're facing is that with

```
ROOT_DIR = "C:\Users\Charlie\"
OBJ_DIR = $(ROOT_DIR)\obj
```

the rule

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.f90
```

expands to

```
"C:\Users\Charlie\"obj/%.o: %.f90
```

which is parsed as the static pattern rule

```
"C: \Users\Charlie\"obj/%.o: %.f90
```

That is to say, with target `"C`, target pattern `\Users\Charlie\"obj/%.o` and prerequisite pattern `%.f90`. make complains that `"C` does not match the pattern `\Users\Charlie\"obj/%.o`.

There is some hacky code in GNU make (at least in MinGW; I think Cygwin behaves differently because it expects you to work with its unix-ish directory structure) to recognize absolute Windows paths, but it does not handle quoting. As long as your `OBJ_DIR` does not contain spaces, using

```
ROOT_DIR = C:\Users\Charlie\
```

should make the Windows path recognition kick in.

However...it is rather unusual to see absolute paths in handcrafted Makefiles. Are you sure you want to do it this way? A more common approach would be to work with relative paths so that the Makefile does not have to be changed if the source code is copied to a different directory. Assuming the Makefile is in the root directory, that would be

```
ROOT_DIR = .
```

or just nixing the `ROOT_DIR` variable altogether and saying

```
MOD_DIR = mod
OBJ_DIR = obj
```

Oh, and to answer the next question that's going to crop up: In order to make `make` use the

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.f90
```

rule, you'll need to make `$(TARGET)` have prerequisites that match the `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o` pattern. That could be

```
OBJS_F = $(patsubst %.f90,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS_F)))
```

Comment: When I try what you suggested, I get the error 
"gmake: *** No rule to make target `obj/constants.o', needed by `parametricStudy'
.  Stop."

Comment: I think what I'm not understanding is what your saying about $(TARGET) having prerequisites that match the $(OBJ_DIR)%.o pattern.. Does that mean that the main program needs to be in the .o directory?..

Comment: Where the main program lies does not matter, but its prerequisites have to match the pattern for a rule that knows how to make them. Hmmm...I think I see the problem. With `(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.f90`, the `.f90` files would have to lie directly in the working directory, which is not the case. And it's difficult to reconstruct the `%.f90` on which a particular `%.o` depends. Your original makefile doesn't do that either, though, so you should at least be able to reproduce the old behavior (that everything is recompiled when one .f90 changes) with `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRCS_F)`

Comment: Im really new to using make files.. I would like if only the files that need to be compiled are compiled when changes are made to .f90 files.. I may re-post this question with a different, more appropriate title, and go through the errors and issues with each form of the make files that I've tried..